# AVD Manager showing only one target option

Tags: android, android-studio

I started with android studio and while I try to create a new device the AVD manager showing only one target i,e 4.2.2 as shown in the following figure. But in eclipse it is showing all the options.

[image]. How to create a new emulator the target 2.3.3.

Answer (score 0):

Because both SDK folders are separately located. If you look close you will see that there is an SDK folder inside the Android Studio installation. The target OS directly loaded from this location.

Answer (score 0):

To show additional options in the target dropdown list, e.g. Android 2.2 (API Level 8) and Android 4.0 (API Level 14), you need to download those versions through SDK Manager first.

Only you download those SDK versions like 2.2 and 4.0, then they will show up as options in AVD Manager for you to create new devices of those versions.